# OpenGL: how to setup renderer to show no shadows, lights, and no color shades?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rendering, render

So all I need is simple: if object color is (255, 10, 10) then each visible point of it shall be rendered as (255, 10, 10). No lights, no shadows, no shades, no reflections/refractions and no transparency. I only want to provide vertex meshes and colors for them and see them rendered. Can such thing be implemented with OpenGL (on Renderer setup level - not via post/pre shading)?

Comment: Your question is unclear: OpenGL has no shadows, lights, reflections, refraction, etcetera, *by default*. In fact you must work hard to get them. So, likely your question is missing some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the lighting :

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Comment: I'm confused how this answer reconciles with ybungalobill's comment.

Comment: @R..: It means that myWallJSON likely copied his code from somewhere, doesn't understand what it does, and needs to be told how to turn off stuff that the copied code does.